# Алгоритм: как перевернуть число?

Tags: c#

у нас есть 5 значное число, например: 51351, каким образом можно его перевернуть, чтобы было 15315, без использования циклов, условий, я еще не дошел до этого, спасибо заранее

Comment: А если есть число 10000, то как должна перевернутая версия выглядеть?

Comment: также, 00001. Да и мне не понадобиться такое число, так как суть задания в проверке элегантности числа.

Comment: Тогда это не число, а строка из цифр. `Console.WriteLine(new string("51351".Reverse().ToArray()));` или так `Console.WriteLine(string.Concat("51351".Reverse()));`

Comment: А что если, использовать не только это число, чтобы это работало с любыми числами. По типу, если брать трехзначное число, можно использовать эту формулу:
int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int n = (n / 100) + (n / 10 % 10 * 10) + (n % 10 * 100);

Comment: А вы попробуйте.

Comment: В этом то и проблема, не понимаю, как это сделать с 5 значным числом....

Comment: Сконвкртируйте в строку, разверните строку как последовательность символов, сконструируйте из развёрнутой последовательности новую строку, сконструируйте её назад в число.

Comment: Особого практического смысла в самоограничении "без циклов, без условий" нет, ну разве что учебно-тренировочных целях. Потому что программисты стараются написать код так, чтобы не пришлось его постоянно переписывать, а без циклов ваш код подходит для пятизначных чисел, а потом у вас потребуются и шестизначные и произвольные. А у вас алгоритм только для пятизначных, опа. Надеюсь, вы это понимаете.

Answer (score 2):

Если без циклов и условий, то вот:

```
int num = 12345, result = 0;
int a = num % 10;
num = num / 10;
result += a * 10000;

a = num % 10;
num = num / 10;
result += a * 1000;

a = num % 10;
num = num / 10;
result += a * 100;

a = num % 10;
num = num / 10;
result += a * 10;

a = num % 10;
num = num / 10;
result += a;

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

1. Нам нужно сначала взять последнюю цифру и поставить её первой из пяти в результат.
   Чтобы взять последнюю цифру, можно найти остаток от деления на 10. `12345 % 10 = 5`
2. Затем ставим в результат первой из пяти цифр: `result += 5 * 10000 = 50000`
3. Далее нам нужно отбросить от изначального числа последнюю цифру, т.к. мы её уже положили в результат, используем целочисленное деление на 10 `12345 / 10 = 1234`
4. Возвращаемся к пункту 1.

Когда вернёмся у нас будет: 1234 % 10 = 4

Теперь эту цифру нужно поставить второй по счёту: `result += 4 * 1000 = 54000`

И так все 5 цифр.

Этот метод не сработает, если будут числа вроде 10000. Тогда остаток от деления даст 0, мы будем умножать 0 на 100000, на 10000, 1000 и т.д. до 1, в итоге вывод будет просто 1.

Но это решается, если мы будем использовать в качестве контейнера для результата строку:

```
int num = 10000;
string result = "";
int a = num % 10;
num = num / 10;
result += a;

a = num % 10;
num = num / 10;
result += a;

a = num % 10;
num = num / 10;
result += a ;

a = num % 10;
num = num / 10;
result += a;

a = num % 10;
num = num / 10;
result += a;

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую!

Answer (score 0):

```c
string input = Console.ReadLine();
char[] inputarray = input.ToCharArray();
Array.Reverse(inputarray);
string output = new string(inputarray);
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
int num = 51351;

int num1 = num%10 * 10000 + (num/10)%10 * 1000 + (num/100)%10 * 100 + (num/1000)%10 * 10 + num/10000;
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Так код будет выглядеть компактнее и для любого положительного int-а

```
int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    string result = "";

    while (num > 0)
    {
        int a = num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
        result += a;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(result);
```